# Webscrape data produces a workbook.close() error. How can I correct it?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, xlsxwriter

I'm attempting to build a webscraper (as a side project) that pulls the reviews out of a hotels [Google Reviews page](https://www.google.com/search?q=melbourne%20doubletree&rlz=1C1GCEB_enAU817AU817&oq=melbourne%20doubletree&aqs=chrome..69i57.6187j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#lrd=0x6ad642b40a5fb91f:0xd4af4255ed578be2,1,,,) and prints them to an Excel sheet. The page is infinite scrolling and indexes by 10 starting at 0. I've been using BeautifulSoup to this end. My code is as follows:

```
import requests
import xlsxwriter
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

index = 0
reviewlist = []
while index <= 700:
    url = "https://www.google.com/async/reviewSort?vet=12ahUKEwibi8-45LriAhUXeisKHbROA6sQxyx6BAgBED0..i&ved=2ahUKEwibi8-45LriAhUXeisKHbROA6sQjit6BAgBEHw&rlz=1C1GCEB_enAU817AU817&yv=3&async=feature_id:0x6ad642b40a5fb91f%3A0xd4af4255ed578be2,review_source:All%20reviews,sort_by:qualityScore,start_index:{},is_owner:false,filter_text:,next_page_token:,_pms:s,_fmt:pc".format(index)
    response = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(response.text, "html.parser")
    tenreviews = soup.findAll("span", {"jsl": "$t t-uvHqeLvCkgA;$x 0;"})
    reviewlist += tenreviews
    index += 10

# Export to Excel sheet
workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('doubletreereviews.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet()

row = 0
for review in reviewlist:
    worksheet.write(row, 0, review)
    row += 1

workbook.close()
```

When running my code, it produces the following TypeError.

```
TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object
```

I've noticed that some elements will print normally while others will trigger the error. For example, if I replace the list with a specific single review by adding the below code before I attempt to export to an Excel sheet, it works, producing an Excel sheet with a single review in A1.

```
reviewlist = reviewlist[4]
```

From this, I've deduced that it has something to do with the fact that review four of the list does not have a child / descendant (unsure if I am using this term correctly which I found in BeautifulSoups documentation) while other reviews do.

Would anyone be able to shed any light on this and help me correct it?

If there are any issues with my question, explanation, or code, feel free to let me know. I'm trying to learn as much as I can!

Comment: Can please paste complete `traceback`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> TypeError: expected string or bytes-like object

because you are trying to write `BeautifulSoup Tag` object

```
worksheet.write(row, 0, review)
```

where `review` is `<class 'bs4.element.Tag'>` instance.

`review` argument must be a `string` or a `number`, not `Tag` type.

Comment: Altered review argument to str(review) and this was solved. Thank you Bharatk!